# how do I skip arrays value in PHP?

Tags: php, arrays, foreach

I need some help, I've got this array:

```
Array ( [0] => 2 [1] => 2 [2] => 1 [3] => 1 [4] => 2 [5] => 2 )
```

And I'm using a foreach

```
foreach( $valortot as $key => $m ) {

$valortot[$key];

echo $valortot[$key];
echo "<br>";

}
```

It's going to output:

```
   2 2 1 1 2 2
```

but I want just to output:

```
   2 1 2
```

How can I do that?

Comment: You want to iterate only distinct array values?

Comment: no, they could be equal but I want to skip do the next.

Comment: What output would you expect if your array was `1, 2, 3, 4, 5`?

Comment: It would be like that:  1,3,5

Comment: So you only want to output every other value? It seems very unclear what you are asking.

Comment: I want to exclude duplicates, if it's not possible I would like to know how to skip for the next value.

Comment: Anything is *possible*. Tell us exactly what you want, what your desired logic is.

Comment: In the array somehow the thing went twice, So I need to remove duplicates or skip them to show.

Comment: John Conde's example helped, thanks guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming you do not want duplicate values printed back-to-back. If so just keep track of the last value printed. If the current value matches it, skip it.

```
$previous = '';
foreach( $valortot as $m ) {
  if($m !== $previous ) {
     echo $m ."<br>";
   };
   $previous = $m;
}
```

Comment: It worked! The way I want, but if I use this inside another foreach?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. You can use this in another foreach including nested foreaches if you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

```
$last_val = NULL;

foreach( $valortot as $m ) {

    if($m != $last_val){  //check if current val equals last val, if it doesn't then echo it
        echo $m;
        echo "<br>";
    }

    $last_val = $m;  //reset last val to $m to check next time around

}
```

Answer (score 0):

If your logic is simply to *output every other element*:

```
for ($i = 0, $length = count($valortot); $i < $length; $i += 2) {
    echo $valortot[$i], '<br>';
}
```

or

```
foreach ($valortot as $i => $value) {
    if ($i % 2 == 0) {
        echo $value, '<br>';
    }
}
```

or

```
echo join('<br>', array_map('current', array_chunk($valortot, 2)));
```